# How to set non-US location in BigQuery ODBC? (Magnitude Simba on Linux)

Tags: linux, google-bigquery, odbc, magnitude, simba

Maybe anybody knows...

I need to connect BigQuery via ODBC driver by Simba (Linux). I've installed it. My datasets located in EU, but every single request via ODBC driver I get "Dataset is not found. Not found: Dataset **** was not found in location US".

What should I do to set another location for all my queries in one connection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ODBC, so I don't know how to actually set the correct values with it, but for API usage of BigQuery, this is done in the `location` part of the request JSON body. Details for general location setting can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#specifying_your_location) and for specific API's they are detailed in the API documentation, fe. [query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#queryrequest), and look at the location key/value pair of the request body.

I know this doesn't answer your question, but I hope it helps getting to it. Be sure to answer your own question once you've found the answer once you figure out how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this thread when trying to get the Simba ODBC Driver working with tables located under a dataset in `asia-south1`.

I found the following link helpful:

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Simba-ODBC-driver-error-quot-Dataset-xx-was-not-found-in/m-p/488010

Seems like it derives the default location from the Dataset provided by the following in your `odbc.ini` file:

```bash
LargeResultsDatasetId=<dataset>
```

Note. In my tests `AllowLargeResults` could still be set to 0 and this works.